# Unable to change product status - for "All store views" (Global Store)

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, save, repository

I am in need to disable a list of SKUs. For that I have created a console command, read the CSV and then setting product as disabled.

I am facing an issue that I am not able to make product disabled for global store.

Whereas my code is working fine for specific store only i.e. if I switch store, product status is disabled else it is enables.

```
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,


             try {
                    $product = $this->_productRepository->get(
                        $sku[0],
                        true/* edit mode */,
                        0/* global store*/,
                        true/* force reload*/
                    );
                    //$product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku[0]);
                    $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
                    $this->_productRepository->save($product);
                } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                    echo $exception->getMessage();exit;
                }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

**[Edit]**
I figured out the cause - in configuration for status attribute I am having scope set to website.
If I set it to global and then try it is saving for default value as well.

But as I can not change the scope of attribute on production site, any idea how I can save it for default value as well even if attribute has "website" level scope.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer is anyone else running into the same issue. I was able to fix my issue by below mentioned logic instead.

```
                    $store_id = 0; // or 1,2,3,... ?
                    $attribute_code = 'status';
                    $value = '2';
                    $product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku[0]);
                    $product->addAttributeUpdate($attribute_code, $value, $store_id);
```